# item.selected Not working in ListBox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lbUnassigned.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string itemName = item.Text.ToString();
            string itemValue = item.Value.ToString();

            lbAssigned.Items.Add(new ListItem(itemName, itemValue));

            lbUnassigned.Items.Remove(lbUnassigned.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Which is pretty much identical to an example given in the .NET 3.5 book I have, yet when stepping through this procedure the item.selected if false every time, even though I am selecting at least one value in the ListBox.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the items source specifed in the control mark up as well as the c# code?

Comment: Wild guess..you must be binding the ListBox again before reaching this part of the code... Can you post the rest part of the code?

Comment: Usually when something like this happens the reason is control rebinding. Check if you have the if(!IsPostBack) on your page load when binding the control

Comment: How do I accept Atzoya's comment as the answer, he's right?

Comment: added my comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when something like this happens the reason is control rebinding. Check if you have the if(!IsPostBack) on your page load when binding the control